Prevent django from writing e-mail information to stdout
I'm using django 2.2. with python 3.6. In some cases my server stores stdout into a log used by managers.
For some reason django started to write to stdout at send-mail some time ago. The managers do not like it because it looks like en error case for them.
So the following sends the e-mail, but also writes to stdout:
^C(venv) > python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.15 (default, Sep 15 2021, 12:00:00)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from django.core.mail import send_mail

In [2]:     send_mail(
   ...:         'Problems in sync script',
   ...:          "kukkuu",
   ...:         'pxpro_sync@<myOrg>',
   ...:         ['<myEmail>'],
   ...:         fail_silently = False,)
connection: {'fail_silently': False, 'host': 'localhost', 'port': 25, 'username': '', 'password': '', 'use_tls': False, 'use_ssl': False, 'timeout': None, 'ssl_keyfile': None, 'ssl_certfile': None, 'connection': None, '_lock': <unlocked _thread.RLock object owner=0 count=0 at 0x7fa8e5a01180>}
mail: <django.core.mail.message.EmailMultiAlternatives object at 0x7fa8e59b4ba8> <class 'django.core.mail.message.EmailMultiAlternatives'>
Out[2]: 1

How can I get just e-mails sent without anything (like "connection:...") displayed into stdout ?
I does not matter whether I define EMAIL_BACKEND as 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' or not.

That code appears to be a test run using localhost rather than an actual email server.

Do you have a LOGGING dict in your settings.py? If yes, can you show how that looks like?

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('pxpro-service')
LOG_LEVEL = settings.LEVEL
logging.basicConfig(
filename=settings.LOGFILE_NAME,
filemode='w',
level=LOG_LEVEL,
format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s')

When I run the same code (i.e. the same logging setting) with python 3.8 and django 4.2 in the same machine I get no unwanted connection-info into stdout
